# How to grant camera permission in react native expo app (android)

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

My code is :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

import Screen from "./app/components/Screen";

export default function App() {
  async function permisionFunction() {
    const result = await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync();
    if (!result.granted) {
      console.log(result);
      alert("need access to gallery for this app to work");
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  return <Screen></Screen>;
}
```

I denied the permissions for camera when it was promted for the first time.
Now whenever I opens the app always `need access to gallery for this app to work` this message is shown up. for android.

- I tried by giving all the permissions to the expo app in settings but still same msg appears.
  How can I solve this.

Answer (score 6):

Use `expo-camera`module to access device camera.

I have curated the working example of small app with which you can access pictures from gallery as well as device camera.

**Working App: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/camera-permission)**

[image]

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function Add({ navigation }) {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const [galleryPermission, setGalleryPermission] = useState(null);

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState(null);
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState(Camera.Constants.Type.back);

  const permisionFunction = async () => {
    // here is how you can get the camera permission
    const cameraPermission = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();

    setCameraPermission(cameraPermission.status === 'granted');

    const imagePermission = await ImagePicker.getMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(imagePermission.status);

    setGalleryPermission(imagePermission.status === 'granted');

    if (
      imagePermission.status !== 'granted' &&
      cameraPermission.status !== 'granted'
    ) {
      alert('Permission for media access needed.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permisionFunction();
  }, []);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(null);
      console.log(data.uri);
      setImageUri(data.uri);
    }
  };

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [1, 1],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageUri(result.uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.cameraContainer}>
        <Camera
          ref={(ref) => setCamera(ref)}
          style={styles.fixedRatio}
          type={type}
          ratio={'1:1'}
        />
      </View>

      <Button title={'Take Picture'} onPress={takePicture} />
      <Button title={'Gallery'} onPress={pickImage} />
      {imageUri && <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ flex: 1 }} />}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  cameraContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  fixedRatio: {
    flex: 1,
    aspectRatio: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0.1,
    padding: 10,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the user has denied the camera permission the first time, the second time you request permission with requestCameraPermissionsAsync() the answer will always be "denied" unless the user manually changes the permission in the app settings.

```
import { Linking } from "react-native";
import { useCameraPermissions } from "expo-image-picker";

export default function App() {

    const [status, requestPermissions] = useCameraPermissions();

    const requestPermissionAgain = () => {
        Linking.openSettings();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!status?.granted) requestPermissions();
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem... I'm using expo SDK 42 and after a denied answer the permissions request does not trigger again anymore.

Anyway, You have some mistakes in your code, you have to watch the status property of the permissions response.

this is how to check the response status

```js
const requestPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const {
        status,
      } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      console.log('status lib', status);
      setHasPickerPermission(status === 'granted');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
    try {
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      console.log('status camera', status);
      setHasCameraPermission(status === 'granted');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestPermissions();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's mention in [doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) Configuration.

In managed apps, Camera requires `Permissions.CAMERA`. Video recording requires `Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING`.

Comment: That's deprecated now. See: https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-41-12cc5232f2ef